# Inequation / binomial formula

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequation: $ (-av-w sinu + b)^2 \leq 3(a^2v^2 + w^4 u^4+b^2)$
How does this work. Maybe I have to use: $2uv \leq u^2+v^2$?
Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: What do we know about the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Expanding the left-Hand side we obtain:
$$a^2 v^2-2 a b v+2 a v w \sin (u)+b^2-2 b w \sin (u)+w^2
   \sin ^2(u)$$

Comment: Thank you: For example I get $ 2abv \leq a^2v^2b$?

Comment: Is that the right way?

Comment: I have it reduced to $$2avw\sin(u)-2bw\sin(u)+w^2\sin^2(u)\le (av+b)^2+3w^4u^4+b^2$$

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear:)